# Getting out of an OpenID lockout

Tags: support, openid, login

The problem I've had is the following:

I used to log in to Stack Exchange sites with the [myVidoop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xcmY8Pk-qEk&t=2m41) OpenID provider. This provider is not supported anymore. I luckily had a cookie on my browser, which made me remain logged in to Stack Overflow, and I was able to switch OpenID providers. But even though I have my accounts on Server Fault, Meta and Super User related to this one, I can't log in on those sites. I didn't have time to swap OpenID providers there, so I've been locked out.

What can I do?

Comment: can't what?  Post on Meta?  We kind of need a real question to move to meta here.  Otherwise, it's just going to get closed as "Not a real question."

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's no longer possible to set separate login providers on different sites as universal login is now implemented, so this isn't relevant today. Even before that, shortly after this question was asked, global auth was implemented so other sites would detect one's logged in to another site, which also made this obsolete. (I had firsthand experience with it back in the day)

Comment: @Sonic not that it matters now, but the correct close reason would be "No longer reproduceable". This question is about something that was part of Stack Exchange.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard I often use custom comment close reasons when it may not be clear to others why a question can no longer be reproduced. In this case, I figured that some people may incorrectly think it still applies to the modern login provider scheme, which is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

Email the team, as described on the "contact us" link at the bottom of every page.

team@stackoverflow.com